# How to run regular bash from cmder and not wsl bash?

Tags: windows, bash, git, docker, git-bash

After I install docker on my windows 10, I get a message that I need to install wsl2 also. - So I did.

But now my [`cmder`](https://cmder.net/) run `wsl` when I run bash command. before it just run the `bash` command.

the problem with bash `wsl` most of my commands are not avaiable.

How to restore the settings to run `bash` not by `wsl`?

Answer (score 0):

In Cmder, open settings: `Win` + `Alt` + `P`

1. Under Startup > Tasks, add a task called {bash} with the following settings:

   Task parameters (set icon):

```
      For Cmder icon:  /icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder.exe"
```

```
      For Git icon: /icon "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git.ico"
```

Commands (open Git's bash shell):

```
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -l -new_console:d:%USERPROFILE%
```

2. Under Startup, set startup options to `Specified name task --> {bash}`

Please check below couple of articles and should solve an issue.

> https://gist.github.com/nickautomatic/02ccb76292f7f8d9767e
>   https://gingter.org/2016/11/16/running-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-in-cmder/